# integer constant is so large that it is unsigned when assigning max type value to enum

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, enums

Here is my enum declaration :

```
enum connection_primary_identifier_e : uint64_t
{
    INVALID_IDENTIFIER = std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type<connection_primary_identifier_e>::type>::max(),
}
```

(same happens if I use `uint64_t` directly as the type, also if I use `-1` or `-1ULL`)

When I try to compile the file I get the following errors / warnings :

```
error: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned [-Werror]
error: narrowing conversion of ‘18446744073709551615I128’ from ‘__int128’ to ‘unsigned int’ inside { } [-Werror=narrowing]
error: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Werror=overflow]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The really weird thing is, the errors are actually produced for non-existing lines (line number is 3 after the last line on file) on another file (which uses the enum), I made sure it isn't a missing parentheses or anything like that.

Update:
Using `uint32_t` doesn't produce the error.

Using g++ (GCC) 4.8.3

Comment: Unable to reproduce (`g++ --version` = `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4`). Did you accidentally compile/include another version of the enum?

Comment: It is working [here](http://goo.gl/rW6mti)

Comment: Notice these are warnings which are treated as errors, Also, I've updated the question with the correct GCC version, sorry for that.

Comment: Prepare a MVCE that produces the same warnings (e.g. add `#include <limits>`), use `-c` to compile that file only, and use `-v` for verbose output. Add both the MVCE and the verbose compiler output to your question. It could be a bug specific only to 4.8.3, but I cannot imagine how something like that would happen (it's also not in the bug tracker).

Comment: @Zeta, I've tried to reproduce it using online compilers but I failed doing so, on the other hand, I didn't find any online website which allows me to select the compiler version.

Comment: To narrow down the problem, could you please remove your use of `std::underlying_type<...>` and replace it with `uint64_t`?

Comment: I've stated I did try.. The same happened ... Only when using uint32_t / int32_t the problem was gone, as I'd the max size for the enum is 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

Might be because [`std::underlying_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) was initially underspecified and didn't require a complete type. This unintentionally allowed precisely this code, which uses `connection_primary_identifier_e` while it's still incomplete.

Starting with C++17, your code is definitely illegal.

Comment: The same happened when I used `uint64_t`, so I'm not sure the `underlying_type` is the issue here